# Rewrite a url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have page I created witch display's topics by there ID in the database. It is `topic.php?id=35` which would go to a topic. I want to rewrite that with .htaccess to `/topics/id/IDNUMBERHERE`

Any ideas how I could go about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^topics/id/([0-9][0-9])$ /topics/id/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^topics/id/([0-9][0-9])/$ /topic.php?id=$1
```

This will transform http://www.yourwebsite.com/topic.php?id=35 to http://www.yourwebsite.com/topics/id/35 I think.. not entirely sure.

More information can be found [here](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Niels** has the right idea. But this is a little more concise and works for ids other than 2 digits.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topics/id/(\d+)/?$ /topic.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Also, if this is for SEO purposes, I would advise dropping the `/id/` portion. It provides no keyword value and as a sub directory can actually lower your page value.